# How do I integrate facebook login on my website on localhost using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I am trying to integrate facebook login on my website on localhost using CodeIgniter. I created a `fb_login` function in controller `user.php` where different functions are also defined. The problem is that when I call `fb_login` function from `login_view.php` then it doesn't work, where as when `fb_login` is defined in a separate controller and called, its function then works...

Here's the code:

user.php (controller)

```
public function fb_login(){

        $this->load->library('facebook');                
        $user = $this->facebook->getUser();
        echo $user;
        if ($user) {
            try{
            $user_profile = $this->facebook->api('/me?locale=en_US&fields=name,email');
            }
            catch (FacebookApiException $e){
                $user = null;
            }
        }
        else{
            $this->facebook->destroySession();
        }

        if ($user) {
            $logout_url = site_url('user/logout');
            $user_data =array(
                'user_id' => $user_profile['id'],
                'username' => $user_profile['name'],
                'logged_in' => true
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
            $this->load->view('profile_view');//,$logout_url,$user_profile);
        }
        else{
            $login_url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'redirect_uri' => site_url('user/login_page'),
                'scope' => 'email'
                ));

            $this->load->view('login_view',$login_url);    
        }

}
```

but this works fblogin.php (controller)

```
class Fblogin extends CI_Controller { 

    public function Login(){


        $this->load->library('facebook');

        $user = $this->facebook->getUser();
        echo $user;
        if ($user) {
            try{
            $data['user_profile'] = $this->facebook->api('/me?locale=en_US&fields=name,email');
            }
            catch (FacebookApiException $e){
                $user = null;
            }
        }
        else{
            $this->facebook->destroySession();
        }

        if ($user) {
            $data['logout_url'] = site_url('fblogin/logout');     
        }
        else{
            $data['login_url'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'redirect_uri' => site_url('fblogin/login'),
                'scope' => 'email'
                ));

        }
        $this->load->view('login',$data);
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->load->library('facebook');
        $this->facebook->destroySession();
        redirect('fblogin/login');
    }

}
```

Comment: "then it doesn't work" -- Could you please define what that means? Does it give an error? What is the url you are sent to? What response do you get, that you know it doesn't work vs the response you get when it works?

Comment: Also, can you please post the remainder of your `user` controller? If it's working in `fblogin` controller...it only stands that it would work the same in the other, unless again, something is vastly different between the two controllers when initialized, or if you have a route that is hosing things up.

Comment: it does not give any error.... i give this url  `<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/user/fb_login">Login using Facebook</a>` in my 'login_view.php' view to login using facebook.. but it only works when i login in using `fblogin` controller when logged in using this and then click on  `<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/user/fb_login">Login using Facebook</a>` this then it login..

Comment: Right, I get that, but what I'm saying is...how exactly do you know it isn't working? What feedback are you getting? Is it a 404 page? There has to be some kind of response you receive when you click on `index.php/user/fb_login` -- What is that response? What do you see in your network panel in dev tools?

Comment: in response it reloads the `login_view` view..

Comment: when it isn't working in response it reloads the `login_view` view.. when it works it loads the `profile_view` view...

Answer (score 0):

In [Facebook Developer](http://www.facebook.com/developers/), set the "Site URL" to your local address, "http://localhost/[yourSiteName]".

Facebook does not redirect back to your server. FB JavaScript plugin does and it runs in the context of your browser, which knows where "localhost" points to.

And do not forget to change it back to your domain when your done.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine this has something to do with the urls/routes you are using since it works from from one controller and not the other. Be certain you are calling the correct url `/controller/method` and not just calling it like `/method` thinking that will hit the appropriate controller method.

Comment: i recheck its correct.. but here another problem occur if login using fblogin controller and then login using user controller then it logged in else not

Comment: It's hard to help you troubleshoot this because you say "when it's called from another controller, it works..." and yet the functionality you have defined in the two controllers is different. For example...the url `'/me?locale=en_US&fields=name,email'` vs simply `me` ... Are you receiving specific PHP errors? Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: the url '/me?locale=en_US&fields=name,email' and me is not the issue.... no php error received...

Comment: Right...I wasn't implying that it was...just that there are other differences as well between the two...so it may be helpful to compare the two as closely as possible, and also posting your view code. How are these functions called? Are you calling them via JS?

Comment: no i am not calling them via JS... calling it by ' <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/user/fb_login"> '